# Bluetooth Permission Denied (13) error 

Tags: 11.10, permissions, bluetooth

After upgrade to Oneiric Ocelot, my Bluetooth is broken. It can recognize the device (my phone) and "Pair" with it (exchange passcodes) but when I try to Send Files to my phone it fails with "Permission Denied (13)" Error.I didn't have this problem in 11.04. Any help appreciated. Also, Send Files works perfectly in the other direction [ Phone -to- PC is ok, but PC -to- phone fails ]

Comment: I have the same problem, there is a bug filed for it so you might want to follow it: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-bluetooth/+bug/872044

Comment: [What to do with questions that describe known bugs?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) this has been reported on [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-bluetooth/+bug/872044) and as such is now closed. For further information, work arounds, and progress, please subscribe to the bug.