# Bluetooth Connection Reconnecting Problem With All Samsung Phones!

Tags: bluetooth

I have samsung corby 2 s3850 and galaxy s2. both phone have same bluetooth problem. in ubuntu 11.10, when i trying to connect my phone using "DUN" it connects for first time. but after disconnecting it, when i trying to reconnect it shows permission error (13) problem. All most samsung phones have the same problem.

"Is there any solution for this problem." B_cuz i love ubuntu very much!

" The Great Free Operating System For Human Beings! "

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this problem when I tried to install Adesk animation wallpaper. Upon not be able to successfully get it working I uninstall it only to be faced with the problem, 'Bluetooth Permission Denied error(13)' each time I tried to transfer files from my Samasung galaxy s II to my system. The following solution helped, which is a repeat post by AskUbuntu.com on link below.

link [Bluetooth permission denied denerror 13](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67026/bluetooth-permission-denied-13-error)

Solution:

```
apt repo upgrade as below



sudo add-apt-repository ppa:blueman/ppa



sudo apt-get update



sudo apt-get upgrade
```

It worked for me.I had the same error about two days ago.